# Objective-C: Better animation

Tags: objective-c, image, animation, move

Im working on a simple cups and ball game and right now I am making the cups move by using

_image.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:...
and then having all of the images in the animation but each animation is about 200 images which is making it really big and slow, is there a way to have each cup move along a curve I set and just have the one image of the cup instead of the thousands for all the animations?

And also I plan to be able to have different cups to choose from, is there a way I can put all the cups in a sprite sheet instead of having each individual image? I do not want to use cocos2d because I am not familiar with it and do not want to restart this project.

Comment: can you provide gif or video of the animation that you are trying to make?

Comment: If you think `animationImages` animation is the way animation is done on iOS in general, you are much mistaken. iOS has wonderful built-in powerful facilities for actually animating visible objects. Why not use it? Why not use one image of the cup and then animate the image view itself, using UIView animation or Core Animation? Using "keyframe" animation, you can readily animate movement along a path.

Comment: Im trying to make an animation like this http://gifmaker.cc/PlayGIFAnimation.php?folder=2015041214Mei8NIXcdu2ic9IDKCebOd&file=output_Qzngha.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into SpriteKit.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Specifically, here's an example for moving an object along a curve:

http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/moving-sprites-path-sprite-kit